# Ajax Problem in IE

Tags: ajax, mootools

This chunk of code works fine on FireFox but in IE it gives runtime error when I try to dump the contents from response returned from AJAX response.I am using mootools to make Ajax call.

```
//on dom ready...  
window.addEvent('domready', function() {  

    /* ajax alert */  <br/>
    $('ajax-alert').addEvent('click', function(event) {
        //prevent the page from changing
        event.stop();
        //make the ajax call
        var req = new Request({
        method: 'get',
        url: $('ajax-alert').get('href'),
        data: { 'do' : '1' },
        onRequest: function() { alert('Request made. Please wait...'); },
        onComplete: function(response) {
            alert(response);// Getting response and able to see that in alert 
            /*line underneath fives runtime error in IE , works fine in FireFox */
            document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML  = response;
            //this line gives run time error on IE
        }
    }).send();
});
```

Comment: Sorry that was typo error.I edited my question.It does not work.

Comment: he probably gets the infamous 'unknown runtime error' when he's updating the innerHTML with fragments IE does not like. basically, it's to do with html you are injecting and the element you are injecting it into, particularly if its non-block - eg, display inline. post the html relevant pls.

Comment: i agree with dimitar....we need to know where this is being embedded and what is being embedded.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to happen when the returned response is not a valid X/HTML. I suggest you validate the page with the response returned in it. As [Dimitar Christoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126998/dimitar-christoff) has mentioned, watch out for inline elements containing block elements.